# Is there anyway to repeatedly grab `pkg.json` version as a variable to replace the version of `index.js` file in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt build. There are `grunt-bump` and `grunt-replace` in it. I use `grunt-bump` to bump up one version up in `pkg.json` every time I run it. And I'd also want to replace the `index.js` version with `pkg.json` version number every time when I run `grunt-replace`. However, I can't do it repeatedly because once the variable`@@package gets replaced, the variable is no longer there.

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initconfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readjson('package.json'),

bump: {
  options: {
    files: ['package.json'],
    updateconfigs: [],
    commit: false,
    commitmessage: 'release v%version%',
    commitfiles: ['package.json'],
    createtag: false,
    tagname: 'v%version%',
    tagmessage: 'version %version%',
    push: false,
    pushto: 'upstream',
    gitdescribeoptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d',
    globalreplace: false,
    prereleasename: false,
    metadata: '',
    regexp: false
  }
},

replace : {
  dist : {
    options : {
      patterns : [
        {
          match: 'packageJsonVersion',
          replacement: '<%= pkg.version %>';
        }
      ]
    },

    files : [
      {
        expand : true,
        flatten : true,
        src : [ 'index.html' ],
        dest : './'
      },
    ]
  }
 },
});

grunt.loadnpmtasks('grunt-bump');
grunt.loadnpmtasks('grunt-replace');

grunt.registertask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>


  <script src="index.@@packageJsonVersion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I have my base `index.html` file containing the variables to be replaced in my `src` folder but I actually copy the file and perform the replace in the `build` folder (or whatever folder is actually containing your prod static assets). This way, the base file is never altered.
Maybe you could change the `dest` and make your web server point to the prod version of your index.html?

```
files : [
      {
        expand : true,
        flatten : true,
        src : [ 'index.html' ],
        dest : 'build/index.html'
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I ended up doing last week.